# How to customize the size of JCoverFlip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have recently started trying to implement JCoverflip into my website and I currently have what is displayed on this link [Current Implementation](http://www.jcoverflip.com/files/docs/jcoverflip-demo/index.html)

However I want to be able to customize the size of the covers so I can use screenshots instead of these smaller covers. I am provided with some customization documentation on their website: [Customization Options](http://www.jcoverflip.com/documentation/advance-customization) but I don't know how to use this or style the sizes of the images and container.

The current CSS styles that are provided and used are below:

```
      .ui-jcoverflip {
    position: relative;
  }

  .ui-jcoverflip--item {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
  }

  /* Basic sample CSS */
  #flip {
    height: 200px;
    width: 630px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }

  #flip .ui-jcoverflip--title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #555;
  }

  #flip img {
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
  }

  #flip a {
    outline: none;
  }


  #coverflowwrapper {
    height: 300px;
    width: 630px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto;
  }

  .ui-jcoverflip--item {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

   #scrollbar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    display:block;

  }
```

Could someone please help as I'm confused how to use the documentation provided?

Help would be much appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the image sizes and spacing by overruling the default values using the [beforeCss, afterCss and currentCss](http://www.jcoverflip.com/documentation/advance-customization#section-options) from jCoverflip. Here's my code (notice the width and height attributes):

```
$('#flip').jcoverflip({
        time: 300, // fade time
        beforeCss: function( el, container, offset ){
            return [
                $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el, { left: ( container.width( )/2 - 280 - 190 *offset )+'px', bottom: '20px' }, { } ),
                $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el.find( 'img' ), { opacity: 0.7, width: '150px', height: '84px' }, {} )
            ];
        },
        afterCss: function( el, container, offset ){
            return [
                $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el, { left: ( container.width( )/2 + 180 + 190 *offset )+'px', bottom: '20px' }, { } ),
                $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el.find( 'img' ), { opacity: 0.7, width: '150px', height: '84' }, {} )
            ];
        },
        currentCss: function( el, container ){
            return [
                $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el, { left: ( container.width( )/2 - 100 )+'px', bottom: '-10px' }, { } ),
                $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el.find( 'img' ), { opacity: 1.0, width: '250px', height: '141px' }, { } )

            ];
        }
    });
```

and here's my html:

```
        <div id="flip">
            <div class="flip_item">
                <img src="img/1.jpg" />
                <p class="caption">Product 3</p>
                <div class="info">
                    <div class="descr">Vius, quacins id urna et augue facilisis dictum. </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flip_item">
                <img src="img/2.jpg" />
                <p class="caption">Product 5</p>
                <div class="info">
                    <div class="descr">Nullad urna et augue facilisis dictum. </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This did not work. I used your code and all that appeared was one large container and it wouldnt move when I clicked on it? @paul

Comment: It work for me, but I got a question... could someone explain me this segment of code:     container.width( )/2 - 280 - 190 *offset

Comment: Wow, that's immensely helpful, especially the parts with random numbers in it. :)